# Built strong base for Unsupervised Learning

Tags: scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, csv

I’m am new into machine learning, recently I have put a task upon my shoulders to Detect Outliers in Dataset.

The anomaly detection should be done using Unsupervised learning and preferably use Scikit-Learn

Can anyone give me any good source or course where I can specific dive into this ?
It so saturated that I don’t know where to start, a guidance on how to tackle this problem would be more than appreciated.

My dataset is in a form of a dataframe in a csv file

Comment: I'd suggest you start by plotting your data and observe manually whether you have outliers before using a library. also you don't give any detail about the kind of data you have.